# Inserting a temporary table with cursor search function to an existing SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am needing help with trying to join a there two queries. 
The first query is my main query for the report i am trying to build.

```
PARAMETERS [DocumentNo] String "", [hideComments] boolean False;

Select cus.name, cus.addra, cus.addrb, cus.addrc, cus.addrd, cus.addre, cus.pcode as PostCode, br.name As BranchName, br.addra As BrAddrA, br.addrb As BrAddrB, 
br.addrc As BrAddrC, br.addrd As BrAddrD, br.addre As BrAddrE, br.postcode As postcodebr, br.Phonenumber as brphonenumber, v.make as vmake, v.YoM as vyear, v.model as vmodel, v.carcolour as vcolor, v.pkey as license, v.state as vstate, V.mileage as mileageout
,h.datetime, h.document, h.acct, h.inits, h.payref, h.corder, h.goods, h.vat,
(Case IsNull(p.supppart,'') when '' then l.part else p.supppart end) part, l.bopdes,
l.qty, l.unit, c.a2 As 'WorkOrderComments'
from jheads h
inner join jlines l on l.document = h.document
inner join customer cus on cus.keycode = h.acct
left join plines p on l.porder = p.document + '/' + cast(p.seqno as varchar(3))
left join codes c on c.keycode= h.branch and c.prefix='WA' and c.subkey1=0
left join branches br on br.branch = h.branch 
left join vehicles v on v.Custacnum = h.acct
where H.Document= [DocumentNo]
```

The information i am needing to add to this report query is; i need the due date for two types based in the "reminders" table. How this information works is that the type column is populated with one of two options 'EMSN or 'INSP. the "VRM" coloumn from this table related to the "pkey" from vehicles table which is all ready in the first query. The VRM is the license of related to an order, but a license can have multiple EMSN and INSP records, there records are sorted sequentically and i need the latest records to be merged into the report for each type ( so i need two record specifically drawn out)

The query i have used to gather this information and temporary store this is

```
use [Masterdatabase]
GO
DECLARE @source TABLE
(
    CustAcNum   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    SeqNo       INT NOT NULL,
    Class       VARCHAR(255),
    [type]      VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Vrm         VARCHAR(12),
    Duedate     DATETIME,
    VehicleId   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
);
DECLARE @filtered TABLE
(
    CustAcNum   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    SeqNo       INT NOT NULL,
    Class       VARCHAR(255),
    [type]      VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Vrm         VARCHAR(12),
    Duedate     DATETIME,
    VehicleId   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
);


INSERT INTO @source
SELECT v.CustAcNum, r.SeqNo, r.[Class], r.[type], r.Vrm, r.Duedate, r.VehicleId
FROM dbo.Vehicles AS v
INNER JOIN dbo.Reminders AS r ON r.VRM = v.Pkey
WHERE r.[Type] = 'EMSN'
GROUP BY v.CustAcNum, r.SeqNo, r.[Class], r.[type], r.Vrm, r.Duedate, r.VehicleId
UNION
SELECT v.CustAcNum, r.SeqNo, r.[Class], r.[type], r.Vrm, r.Duedate, r.VehicleId
FROM dbo.Vehicles AS v
INNER JOIN dbo.Reminders AS r ON r.VRM = v.Pkey
WHERE r.[Type] = 'INSP'
GROUP BY v.CustAcNum, r.SeqNo, r.[Class], r.[type], r.Vrm, r.Duedate, r.VehicleId
ORDER BY v.CustAcNum, r.Seqno DESC;


DECLARE
     @custAcNum VARCHAR(255)
    ,@seqNo     INT
    ,@class     VARCHAR(255)
    ,@type      VARCHAR(255)
    ,@vrm       VARCHAR(12)
    ,@duedate   DATETIME
    ,@vehicleId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

DECLARE source_cursor CURSOR
    FAST_FORWARD
    FOR SELECT * FROM @source WHERE NULLIF(ltrim(rtrim(CustAcNum)), '') IS NOT NULL;

OPEN source_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM source_cursor 
INTO @custAcNum, @seqNo, @class, @type, @vrm, @duedate, @vehicleId;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGiN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @filtered WHERE CustAcNum = @custAcNum AND [type] = @type)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @filtered
        VALUES (@custAcNum, @seqNo, @class, @type, @vrm, @duedate, @vehicleId);
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM source_cursor 
    INTO @custAcNum, @seqNo, @class, @type, @vrm, @duedate, @vehicleId;
END

CLOSE source_cursor;
DEALLOCATE source_cursor;

select * from @filtered;
```

I'm now needing to join these two together and be able to extract the due date out of them for both type's.

I'm stuck on this so any help i would appreciate it.